# Do sinners 'directly' get moksha if they die in Varanasi?

Tags: scripture, sin, kashi

The answers to [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27672/where-in-scriptures-it-is-written-that-those-who-die-in-varanasi-will-never-retu) clearly say that any person who dies in Varanasi will get moksha.

If a sinner dies in Varanasi, will that person get moksha?

Comment: they get moksha,

Comment: Anyone dying in Varanasi will be liberated. The question is whether sinners will have the luck to die there or not.

Comment: @Rickross Yeah... True...

Comment: All the fish in the ganges in varanasi will attain moksha? without realizing that its sivas place..

Comment: Is the "Varanasi" mentioned in the puranas the physical city of Benares or another metaphysical locale like the Meru, considered to be the centre of everything?

Comment: @PrasannaR Yeah... all the creatures present in Kashi...

Comment: First of all one dies there considered varanasi and ganges to be supreme holy place.. first  qulification is okai then they need to perform the prescribed anushandaham as stated in the scripture, Regarding one line and thinking that one can get moksha just by dieing is lving in day dream one had to read all the 18 purunas and conversent i veda and upahinshad philosophy to decipher this one line.. otherwise its waste of birth by following one word living accordingly @rudrasadashiva

Comment: @PrasannaR are you OK buddy ? Who said one have to read all 18 puranas , veda, Upanishads to get moksha ? Brainless yrr... Even a chandala of Varanashi who never read any Shashtras will get Moksha there....  It's stated that no sinners actually can't die in Varanashi... One can die in Kashi by the virtues collected over the past births by him not otherwise...

Answer (score 5):

Any one who dies in Varanasi will get moksha.  I am posting a passage that describes Sri Ramakrishna's experience in Benares.

> The party entered holy Benares by boat along the Ganges. When Sri
> Ramakrishna's eyes fell on this city of Siva, where had accumulated
> for ages the devotion and piety of countless worshippers, he saw it to
> be made of gold, as the scriptures declare. He was visibly moved.
> During his stay in the city he treated every particle of its earth
> with utmost respect. At the Manikarnika Ghat, the great cremation
> ground of the city, he actually saw Siva, with ash covered body, and
> tawny matted hair, serenely approaching each funeral pyre and
> breathing into the ears of the corpses the mantra of liberation; and
> then the Divine Mother removing from the dead their bonds. **Then he
> realized the significance of the scriptural statement that anyone
> dying in Benares attains salvation through the grace of Siva.**

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna translated by Swami Nikhilananda, Introduction**

Answer (score 3):

Not all sinners will get moksha *directly* although they die in Varanasi. **Some have to become Pisacha, and they will get liberated afterwards.**

But it should be noted that no one who dies in Varanasi will take birth, including living animals.

Sinners, in this context, can be divided into two kinds: Sinners who committed their sins at Varanasi and sinners who committed their sins elsewhere. Those who committed sins elsewhere can get liberation directly. But, sinners who committed sins at Varanasi will become a Pisacha, thereby hell and finally attain moksha. Siva has told it to Uma.

> The lord who bore the crescent moon on his forehead recounted the
> greatness of the holy centre:—‘‘O goddess of Devas, the greatness of
> Avimukta cannot be recounted by me in detail. This holy centre is
> honoured by the sages. O fair lady, how shall I tell you in detail the
> merits of Avimukta ?
>
> Sinners who die here shall be liberated even in their very birth. A
> man dispels at Varanasi the sins he has committed elsewhere. **The sins
> committed at Varanasi turn the sinner into a Pisaca and they lead him
> to hell. It is better for men to court Pisacahood after committing
> thousands of sins at Varanasi than to attain the position of Indra a
> thousand times in heaven without the pleasure of being in the city of
> Kasi.** No living animal is reborn if it dies in this place where the
> lord Visvesvara, the lord of Omkara,the lord clad in elephant’s hides,
> is ever present.....
>
> [[73-81,Chapter 103: The glory of Sakti, Linga Purana]](https://archive.org/stream/LingaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart2/Linga%20Purana%20-%20J.L.Shastri%20-%20Part%202#page/n63/mode/2up)

Comment: Wow! Does this apply to the preta to whom Tulsidas used to give water and milk everyday?

Comment: Oh! might be possible because it happened in Varanasi. But I did not read in detail yet. @Archit

Comment: Answer is simply saying that committing sins in a holy place is bigger sin. Since Kashi is the holiest, committing even small sins there assume very big proportions.The same thing is mentioned in Devi Bhagavatam too. @hanugm