# Is the Bindu chakra realization way forgotten now?

Tags: chakras

Is the Bindu now only a symbol of  a forgotten realization ?

Comment: No, it is not forgotten, but it is secret... The Bindu Kshetra is the place of Ajna Chakra and also Avimukta Kshetra which is capable of grating liberation...https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15072/what-is-the-yogic-meaning-of-getting-liberation-by-reaching-varanasi/15073#15073

Comment: Thanx Tezz,. I will do some info checking on the words Avimukta Kshetra and hopefully I will be liberated tomorrow

Comment: "and hopefully I will be liberated tomorrow" : All the best....