# Are Vedas re-revealed every mahayuga, manvantara or kalpa?

Tags: vedas, puranas, sruti

I'm trying to understand, the Hindu timescales, but unable to understand if Vedas are revealed in every mahayuga or manuvantara, does any purana provide info as to when were Vedas revealed?

Comment: Maybe this can help a bit https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/why-do-the-vedas-need-to-be-recompiled-every-dwapara-yuga?rq=1

Comment: @Just_Do_It that's not helpful at all. I'm asking if Vedas were revealed in this satya Yuga or first satya yuga of this kalpa

Comment: But your question doesn't match your comment, is different.

Comment: @Just_Do_It no I am asking the same thing. Satyuga is starting age in each time scale so it will be revealed in first age.

Answer (score 9):

According to the ParAshara Smriti (PS) the Vedas are recalled by Lord BrahmA **at the beginning of each Kalpa.**

> Na kashchitvedakartA cha vedam smritvA chaturmukham |
>  Tathaiva
>   dharmAn smarati manuh kalpAntareantare ||
>
> The author of the Veda there is none ; (he) the fourfaced (God), at
>   each succeeding revolution of a Kalpa, recalls to mind the Veda ; and
>   so does Manu remember the law (at each succeeding revolution of a
>   Kalpa)
>
> **PS 1.21**

According to [Shvetashvatar Upanishad](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/shveta.html?lang=sa), Brahman delivers the Vedas to Brahma while creation:

> यो ब्रह्माणं विदधाति पूर्वं
>                  यो वै वेदांश्च प्रहिणोति तस्मै ।
>   तं ह देवं आत्मबुद्धिप्रकाशं
>                  मुमुक्षुर्वै शरणमहं प्रपद्ये ॥ १८॥
>
> Seeking  liberation,  I  take  refuge  in  the  Lord,  who  projected
>   Brahma  (the  Creator)  and  delivered  to  him  the  Vedas,
>   and  who  is  the  revealer  of  self-knowledge.

So, the answer should be "at the beginning of each new Kalpa".

Also see [How do the Vedas survive during the dissolution of the Universe?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16401/277)

Comment: So the Vedas we have now are from the time of swayambhu manu?

Comment: Yes because as said Manu recalls the Smriti at the onset of each Kalpa and likewise Lord Brahma remembers the Vedas at the same time. @Anisha

Comment: Added one reference from Upanishad and link to the related useful question.

Comment: @Pandya  Do really the god has any shape(fourfaced)

Comment: @Kuhan the four faced God here is Brahma, who is deva in reality meaning divine being-also jiva(mortal) he dies during the end of kalpa he recalls the Veda in the new cycle.

Answer (score 2):

The Vedas are revealed to human civilization only at the beginning of every *Treta* yuga.

Srimad Bhagavatam:

> 11.17.11: In Satya-yuga the undivided Veda is expressed by the syllable om, and I am the only object of mental activities. I become
>   manifest as the four-legged bull of religion, and thus the inhabitants
>   of Satya-yuga, fixed in austerity and free from all sins, worship Me
>   as Lord Haṁsa.
>
> 11.17.12: O greatly fortunate one, at the beginning of Tretā-yuga Vedic knowledge appeared from My heart, which is the abode of the air
>   of life, in three divisions — as Ṛg, Sāma and Yajur. Then from that
>   knowledge I appeared as threefold sacrifice.